# Plain Vanilla Windows vs Windows Server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008, iis

I probably should have asked this question a LONG time ago and I expect to be laughed out of this forum, but I NEED find the answer to this seemingly rudimentary question...

If I intend to host a .NET web application, why would I want to use Windows Server as opposed to plain vanilla Windows? Plain vanilla Windows has IIS so it obviously is capable of serving up web pages to some degree. I can only assume there are some limitations - what are they? Licensing? Limited number of connections? I can't seem to find any decent documentation on this. Can anyone shed some light on this topic for me or point me in the direction of some documentation?

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391989

Comment: Seeing as I wrote the "duplicate", I'm aware. I was told to ask on SF since this is more in your realm. And look, I got a better answer than I did on SO.

Comment: Be aware that there is no such thing as "plain vanilla Windows". Most will assume you are talking about one of the numerous workstation versions, although it's impossible to guess which one, but assumption is the mother of all stuff-ups. Be clear about what you are asking.

Comment: @John Kraft I like to give it 24 hours to give most users a chance to contribute.

Comment: @John Gardeniers I intentionally chose to not restrict the question to a specific version of Windows because I want to know what *all* of the versions have to offer. I think this will be the last time I try to contribute to the SF site. Goodbye.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIS is artificially limited (features, performance) in consumer OSes, keeping licenses cheap. See "IIS 7.0 Editions and Windows" for more details (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc268241.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In addition, Windows Server kernel is tuned for better background task performance than desktop Windows.